# How to display data coming from mongodb to reactjs after clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mern

I am making react project using express.js, mongodb, react.js, and node.js. and trying to fetch data from backend api which is running on port 5000.

When I check the api using `postman`, it is working. And the data is showing in the browser's console. Also, when I press `Get` button as given in the code below, it doesn't work on the browser. But I'm able to see the array data in the browser's console.

`<Button onClick={()=><li>{employeeItem}</li>}>Get</Button>`

Here is my full code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  form,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  ControlLabel,
  Button
} from "react-bootstrap";
import "./App.css";
import { stringify } from "querystring";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.AddName = this.AddName.bind(this);
    this.AddContact = this.AddContact.bind(this);
    this.AddAge = this.AddAge.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      contact: "",
      age: "",
      employees: []
    };
  }
  AddName(e) {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }
  AddContact(e) {
    this.setState({ contact: e.target.value });
  }
  AddAge(e) {
    this.setState({ age: e.target.value });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/employees")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ employees: data }));
  }

  render() {
    const employeeItem = this.state.employees.map(employee => (
      <div key={employee._id}>
        <h3>{employee.name}</h3>
        <p>{employee.contact}</p>
        <p>{employee.age}</p>
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Employee List</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="Layout">
          <form>
            <FormGroup>
              <ControlLabel>Name:</ControlLabel>
              <FormControl
                type="text"
                value={this.state.name}
                placeholder="Employee name"
                onChange={this.AddName}
              />
              <div>
                <ControlLabel>Contact:</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  type="number"
                  value={this.state.contact}
                  placeholder="Mobile number"
                  onChange={this.AddContact}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <ControlLabel>Age:</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                  type="number"
                  value={this.state.age}
                  placeholder="Age"
                  onChange={this.AddAge}
                />
              </div>
            </FormGroup>
            <Button type="submit">Add</Button>
            <Button onClick={() => console.log({ employeeItem })}>Get</Button>
            <Button type="submit">Delete</Button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[on running page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmOfy.png)

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Can you give us a minimal code example? Where is the part you actually query your backend?

Comment: @Almaju I am trying to display the data coming from my database to my page on pressing Get button but is not working. I have shared the screen shot also. When i press Get button the data is coming on the console but i wanted that data to come on my page.

Comment: You can't render the items like you are trying inside a button callback. Where do you want to see those items and when? You are already fetching the data and set your state. Don't you want to see them immediately after the fetch? You can do it with a button of course with 2 options: 1. Trigger the fetch with the button instead of doing it in `componentWillMount` then show items. 2. Pre-fetch but hide the items with a suitable state property. Then change it with the button click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't render an item as you are trying inside an `onClick` callback. You can render the items immediately after fetched them or you can trigger with an `onClick` the fetch or you can hide and show the items.

**Immediately rendering**

```js
const employees = [
  { _id: 1, name: "foo", contact: "abc", age: 20 },
  { _id: 2, name: "bar", contact: "efg", age: 30 },
  { _id: 3, name: "baz", contact: "hij", age: 40 }
];

const fakeRequest = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(employees), 1000));

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    employees: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest().then(employees => this.setState({ employees }));
  }

  render() {
    const employees = this.state.employees.map(employee => (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid black" }} key={employee._id}>
        <h3>Name: {employee.name}</h3>
        <p>Contact: {employee.contact}</p>
        <p>{employee.age}</p>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <p>Data will be fetched in a second automatically.</p>
        {employees}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Get with a button click**

```js
const employees = [
  { _id: 1, name: "foo", contact: "abc", age: 20 },
  { _id: 2, name: "bar", contact: "efg", age: 30 },
  { _id: 3, name: "baz", contact: "hij", age: 40 },
];

const fakeRequest = () => new Promise( resolve =>
  setTimeout( () => resolve( employees ), 1000)
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    employees: [],
  };

  getEmployees = () =>
    fakeRequest()
      .then(employees => this.setState({ employees }))

  render() {
    const employees = this.state.employees.map(employee => (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid black"}} key={employee._id}>
        <h3>Name: {employee.name}</h3>
        <p>Contact: {employee.contact}</p>
        <p>{employee.age}</p>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
      <p>Data will be fetched after the button click.</p>
      <button onClick={this.getEmployees} >Get Employees</button>
      {employees}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Show/hide method**

```js
const employees = [
  { _id: 1, name: "foo", contact: "abc", age: 20 },
  { _id: 2, name: "bar", contact: "efg", age: 30 },
  { _id: 3, name: "baz", contact: "hij", age: 40 },
];

const fakeRequest = () => new Promise( resolve =>
  setTimeout( () => resolve( employees ), 1000)
);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    employees: [],
    showEmployees: false,
  };
    
  componentDidMount() {
    fakeRequest()
      .then(employees => this.setState({ employees }))
  }

  toggleEmployees = () => this.setState( prevState => ({
    showEmployees: !prevState.showEmployees,
  }))

  render() {
    const { showEmployees } = this.state;
    const employees = this.state.employees.map(employee => (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid black"}} key={employee._id}>
        <h3>Name: {employee.name}</h3>
        <p>Contact: {employee.contact}</p>
        <p>{employee.age}</p>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
      <p>Data will be fethced automatically in a second but will be hidden by default. Button click toggles this state.</p>
      <button
        onClick={this.toggleEmployees}
      >
        {
          showEmployees ? "Hide Employees" : "Show Employees"
        }
      </button>
      {this.state.showEmployees && employees}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is great effort shown by you man. Keep up the great work. I hope the solution works for @manish

Comment: Thank you for the appreciation.

Comment: Big thanks, the solution you provided worked for me. Highly appreciate your effort.